# Deterministic integral of a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $Q_t$ be a martingale and 
$$
M_T := \int_0^T Q_t \, dt.
$$ 
Then, is $M_T$ a martingale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $Q_t = B_t$, where $(B_t)_{t\geqslant 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion. Then $d M_t = B_t dt$, so $M_t$ has drift.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspected but couldn't prove.